# Bootstrap tabs in Electron - what am I missing?

Tags: bootstrap-4, electron

This is my .html-page loaded in an Electron window:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Punktskatter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Indata" data-toggle="tab">Indata</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Deklaration" data-toggle="tab">Deklaration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Indata"><p>test1</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Deklaration"><p>test2</p></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        require('./renderer.js')
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    </script>
  </body>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

I´m obviously missing something, but what? Both jquery and bootstrap were installed using npm install jquery -- save / npm install bootstrap --save. And bootstrap is obviously being loaded as it doesn´t present as a normal list.

Comment: check your package json again and try to link bootstrap JS

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "python-shell": "^1.0.6",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "tabs": "^0.2.0"
  }

Comment: This is how it already looks